# Mysql - select records for lat/lng position that users have in their individual distance ranges

Tags: mysql, latitude-longitude

I need to know the best practice (best performance) for a database query for the following scenario (Mysql):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/72191ca/1

I have an "starting-item" (point "Key", blue dot lat:47.471630, lng: 8.297835 ) with a lat/lon postion. In a user table, there are users (A,B,C etc.) with their lat/lon position and their individual ranges in km.

I need to query the users table to find the ids that have the key within their predefined ranges/distance.

The query should be optimized - about 40'000 users to be compared to a "Key" lat/lon position.

This is the current query I use. The performance is quite good, but would there be another solution to do this that can use indexes?

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS users;

CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `user_id` char(1) NOT NULL,
  `lat` decimal(8,5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00000',
  `lng` decimal(8,5) DEFAULT '0.00000',
  `user_range_km` decimal(10,1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1.0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`),
  KEY `lat` (`lat`,`lng`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;


INSERT INTO `users` (`user_id`, `lat`, `lng`, `user_range_km`) VALUES
('A', '47.46911', '8.29560', '0.4'),
('B', '47.48169', '8.30264', '0.4'),
('C', '47.49261', '8.31598', '2.9');

SELECT h.*, ( 6371 * acos( cos( radians(47.471630) ) * cos(  radians( h.lat ) ) * cos( radians( h.lng ) - radians(8.297835) ) + sin( radians(47.471630) ) * sin( radians( h.lat ) ) ) ) AS distance 
FROM users h 
HAVING distance <= h.user_range_km;

+---------+----------+---------+---------------+------------------+
| user_id | lat      | lng     | user_range_km | distance         |
+---------+----------+---------+---------------+------------------+
| A       | 47.46911 | 8.29560 |           0.4 | 0.32671077638732 |
| C       | 47.49261 | 8.31598 |           2.9 |  2.7021411331883 |
+---------+----------+---------+---------------+------------------+
```

In my example, A and C have the Key in their defined distance, so I need to get A and C out of the query. See SQL Fiddle

Comment: sqlfiddle is added

Comment: This is something of a frequently asked question - either here or elsewhere - because lots of people want to sort through vast (and not so vast) collections of geodata point quickly and efficiently. One trick is to exclude data that doesn't fit within a bounding square, with sides equal to double the 'distance'.

Comment: Well, I know how to use a bounding box on a query wheren we have a starting point with a range to query users lat/lngs to exclude users outside the box. But I can't see this scenario here, because every user has an "individual" bounding box. Or do you mean, that the bounding-box lat/lngs would be used in the query instead their lat/lngs directly? Or do I miss a point here?

Comment: As I say, it's a widely discussed topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 5 ways to do that task.  Your code is one of them, the slowest one.  Here is my discussion of them:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/find_nearest_in_mysql

The easiest next step is to use the "bounding box" technique.  It involves adding 2 clauses to the `WHERE` and two `INDEXes`.

Your "multiple users" around one "key" is simply reversing the roles.  The traditional question is about "multiple items (businesses, trucks, etc)" around a "user".  Build the bounding box around the "key".

With only 40K users, the bounding box technique will probably be good enough.

OK, you have an added wrinkle.  Still, the BB should give you a good first filter.  In your example, use

```
MAX(user_range_km) -- which is 2.9
```

as the radius for the BB.  (Or half the width of the "bounding square", as mentioned in a comment.)

Then, instead of simply testing each 'distance' against 2.9, test it against  `user_range_km`.

Comment: Thanks for your comments - now this issue is clear. The query is fine now with the bounding-box.